# I want to return a random sequence in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array defined as

```
array = np.random.randint(10, size = (10,10))
```

and this will return something like this

```
 ([[6, 5, 7, 5, 9, 0, 5, 1, 3, 3],
   [0, 8, 1, 7, 0, 1, 7, 7, 6, 9],
   [4, 1, 7, 5, 5, 9, 6, 8, 9, 2],
   [7, 9, 8, 5, 3, 7, 1, 1, 5, 4],
   [2, 5, 8, 3, 8, 2, 5, 5, 7, 1],
   [1, 5, 3, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2],
   [0, 0, 2, 3, 6, 2, 9, 9, 2, 9],
   [0, 8, 7, 5, 1, 5, 4, 0, 6, 8],
   [9, 9, 8, 2, 9, 0, 1, 6, 8, 3],
   [9, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 6]])
```

and I want a function that will take in two parameters, (the array, and the length of the desired sequence), and will return a sequence of the desired length. The movements should be chosen randomly and should be completely random so I can return a sequence of 1000 in a 10 x 10 array. An example sequence could be(from the array above), [6,5,8,1,7,5,5,9...till this list has a length of 1000, movements can overlap, should be completely random] Here is what has already been tried but doesnt take random movements

```
def generate_all_paths(array, length):
length = length - 1
y_dim = len(array)
x_dim = len(array[0])

paths = [[(y, x)] for y in range(y_dim) for x in range(x_dim)]

directions = [(0, 1), (1, 0), 
              (0, -1), (-1, 0)]
temp_paths = []
for i in range(length):
    random.choice(directions)
    temp_paths.append()
    for direction in directions:
        for p in paths:
            y, x = p[-1]
            y, x = y + direction[0], x + direction[1]
            if -1 < y < y_dim and -1 < x < x_dim and (y, x) not in p:
                temp_paths.append(p + [(y, x)])
            temp_paths.append([y,x])

    paths = deepcopy(temp_paths)
    temp_paths = []
return paths
```

Comment: Please let us know if one of the answers solves the problem and accept it. Otherwise clarify what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create a random path and then follow it throughout the function?

```
import numpy as np

def random_path(array, length):
    output_array = np.zeros((length,))
    trajectory = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=length) 
    step_map = {0 : (1, 0), 1: (0, 1), 2: (-1, 0), 3: (0, -1)} # 0 corresponds to right, 1 to up, etc
    current_index = np.array([0, 0])
    for index, step in enumerate(trajectory):
        current_index = current_index + step_map.get(step)
        new_val = array[current_index[0], current_index[1]]
        output_array[index] = new_val
    return output_array
```

Since arrays work perfectly fine with negative indexing you should be fine for overflow, and this way you basically just follow a random path.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected behaviour at the boundaries of the array?
If you do not want to step across the boundaries, a loop as you did is the easiest way, otherwise a vectorised option as @alwaysmvp45 showed might be better.

Here as a loop:

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_all_paths(arr, length):
    y_dim, x_dim = arr.shape

    directions = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]

    path = [(0, 0)]
    while len(path) < length:
        dir_i = directions[np.random.randint(4)]
        
        y, x = path[-1]
        y, x = y + dir_i[0], x + dir_i[1]
        if -1 < y < y_dim and -1 < x < x_dim:
            path.append((y, x))

    path = np.array(path)
    value_path = arr[path[:, 0], path[:, 1]]
    return value_path
```